# Qube servo 2 control from simulink on ubuntu 20.4

Tags: matlab, servo

I got Qube Servo 2 -usb. To run block scheme on this device from simulink you need to install QUARC REAL-TIME CONTROL SOFTWARE

https://www.quanser.com/products/quarc-real-time-control-software/

This software is only for windows. I would like to run block schemes from simulink on ubuntu 20.4. They have hil sdk for linux -
https://github.com/quanser/hil_sdk_linux_x86_64

You can import functions from this sdk and write code in C/c++ to controll experiments. I tried to import .h files from this sdk into matlab successfully. There are also .a files which need to be imported in order for code to work. Is there a way to import them ?  There is also python driver create from this hil sdk which can controll qube servo 2.

https://github.com/BlueRiverTech/quanser-openai-driver

Is there any chance to create my own blocks to communicate with qube servo 2 without QUARC REAL-TIME CONTROL SOFTWARE ? Is there a way to make it work without their software? Created blocks should run on ubuntu 20.4.